# Monitor maximum resolution only supported in windows 7 using xp drivers

Tags: windows, windows-7

I upgraded from windows vista to windows 7 yesterday. The upgrade went fine and windows properly detected the screen resolutions, but when I selected 1920x1080 it worked but I got black sidebars. This was using the latest driver release from Ati. I also noticed that the selectable refreshrates missed the 75hz option that used to be there in vista.

Now I downgraded the Ati driver to the xp version, this fixes my sidebar problem. But since the driver isn't WDM signed AERO doesn't work.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1920x1080 "monitor" is actually a TV screen; it's a known problem with these new cheap "monitors" and your video card picks up the difference. You'll have to install the most recent drive and play with the scaling settings to get it to display correctly.

If you post the model of your video card I can probably edit in a link to directions. You can also Google "1920x1080 [your video card] scaling problems" and will likely be one of the first few links.